# load text file and populate into the gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a code that let user select the files and load the data in the text files to datagridview.

```
 private void cmdload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Point");
        table.Columns.Add("X");
        table.Columns.Add("Y");
        table.Columns.Add("Z");
        table.Columns.Add("R");
        table.Columns.Add("A");
        table.Columns.Add("B");
        table.Columns.Add("C");

        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "\\Yamaha";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Data Files (*.PNT)|*.PNT";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
         {
             try
             {
                 if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                 {
                     using (myStream)
                     {
                         string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                         using (var reader = File.OpenText(@filename))
                         {
                             string line;
                             while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                             {
                                 string[] parts = line.Split(' ');
                                 table.Rows.Add(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5], parts[6], parts[7]);
                             }
                             dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
```

EDITED:

I have edited my code as suggested but the value just doesn't display. Please advise.

```
private void cmdload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Point");
        table.Columns.Add("X");
        table.Columns.Add("Y");
        table.Columns.Add("Z");
        table.Columns.Add("R");
        table.Columns.Add("A");
        table.Columns.Add("B");
        table.Columns.Add("C");
        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\\"; 
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Data Files (*.PNT)|*.PNT";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {
                        string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                        using (var reader = File.OpenText(filename)) 
                        {
                            string line;
                            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                string[] parts = line.Split(' ');
                                table.Rows.Add(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5], parts[6], parts[7]);
                            }
                            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex) // you need to add the catch block if yo are using try block
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
```

The text file looks like :
[image]

I want the data files to be paste in the gridview when user load the files.
[image]

Now i not sure why my code doesnt work. Can anyone give me an advise please?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Runtime crash? Wrong columns added? No data populated? Wrong data populated? Drinks all the beer in your fridge?

Comment: M@MatthewWatson no error, just the value doesn't display on the gridview. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please have a look :

```
    private void cmdload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Point");
        table.Columns.Add("X");
        table.Columns.Add("Y");
        table.Columns.Add("Z");
        table.Columns.Add("R");
        table.Columns.Add("A");
        table.Columns.Add("B");
        table.Columns.Add("C");
        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\\"; // your directory is also not defined properly
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";// have a look to filter as well
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {
                        string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                        using (var reader = File.OpenText(filename)) // you need not to use '@filename' instead use just 'filename'
                        {
                            string line;
                            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                string[] parts = line.Split(' ');
                                table.Rows.Add(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5], parts[6], parts[7]);
                            }
                            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex) // you need to add the catch block if yo are using try block
            {
            }
        }
```

hope it helps.

Comment: I have edited the code like above but it still the value just did not display on the gridview. please advise.

Comment: @Ren the code above should work, try debugging and see what's wrong(or update your latest code)